# Trying to add a image to firebase V9 storage with react-native expo and redux

Tags: firebase, react-native, redux, expo

**Error given:** [Unhandled promise rejection: FirebaseError: Firebase Storage: String does not match format 'data_url': Must be formatted 'data:[][;base64], (storage/invalid-format)]

I am able to add image to the database, however it is not uploading to the firebase storage. I have changed it to different media types but no luck. I have also tired uploadBytes instead of uploadString and it works but no image displays. Any help would be appreciated!

```
const uploadImageTops = async () => {
    const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db, "tops"), {
      username: "user",
      apparel: "tops",
      color: "black",
      size: size,
      timeStamp: serverTimestamp(),
    });

const imageRef = ref(storage, `tops/${docRef.id}`);

await uploadString(imageRef, cameraImage, "data_url", {contentType:'image/jpg'})
  .then(async (snapshot) => {
    const downloadURL = await getDownloadURL(imageRef);
    await updateDoc(doc(db, "tops", docRef.id), {
      imageUrl: downloadURL,
    });
  })
  .then(navigation.navigate("Home"));
```

};

Answer (score 2):

There's some issue with react-native and firebase when trying to upload the image. Blob is needed to upload image to firebase storage and firestore. Add that blob at the top and make sure you close the blob at the end.

This code worked for me.

```
const uploadImageTops = async () => {
const blob = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onload = function () {
    resolve(xhr.response);
  };
  xhr.onerror = function (e) {
    console.log(e);
    reject(new TypeError("Network request failed"));
  };
  xhr.responseType = "blob";
  xhr.open("GET", cameraImage, true);
  xhr.send(null);
});


const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db, "tops"), {
  username: user,
  apparel: "tops",
  color: color,
  size: size,
  timeStamp: serverTimestamp(),
});

const imageRef = ref(storage, `tops/${docRef.id}`);
const metadata = {
  contentType: "image/jpeg",
};

await uploadBytes(imageRef, blob, metadata)
  .then(async (snapshot) => {
    const downloadURL = await getDownloadURL(imageRef);
    await updateDoc(doc(db, "tops", docRef.id), {
      imageUrl: downloadURL,
    });
    blob.close();
  })
  .then(navigation.navigate("Home"));
```

};

Comment: Phew I was crazy here looking for something and this saved me.

Comment: @Nitin i've been dryving crazy with this issue. Thanks a lot! u re a genius!