# Unable to upload image file to Firebase 9 with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, next.js, firebase-storage

I am trying to let users add and upload an image to firebase. Below is my add image and upload function:

```
  const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = useState(null);

  const addImage = (e) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    if (e.target.files[0]) {
      reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
    }
    reader.onload = (readerEvent) => {
      setSelectedFile(readerEvent.target.result);
    }
  }

  const upload = async () => {
    const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db, 'posts'), {
      username: session.user.username,
      caption: captionRef.current.value,
      timestamp: serverTimestamp()
    });

    const imageRef = ref(storage, `posts/${docRef.id}/image`);

    uploadString(imageRef, selectedFile, 'data_url').then((snapshot) => {
      getDownloadURL(snapshot.ref).then((URL) => {
        updateDoc(
          doc(db, 'posts', docRef.id),
          { image: URL }
        );
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      })
    })
  }
```

Add image and upload components:

```
    <div>
      <input
        type='file'
        onChange={addImage}
      />
    </div>

    <button onClick={() => upload()}>
      <div style={{ color: 'white' }}>
        Upload
      </div>
    </button>
```

I don't receive any errors when the upload function is run but no image file gets uploaded to the firebase storage no matter how long I wait. However, the doc gets added to the firestore database so this means that the upload function is able to run and connect to firebase. I am able to display the image from the state so it doesn't seem to be a problem with the image. Below is my firebase config:

```
import { initializeApp, getApps, getApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
import { getStorage } from "firebase/storage";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyAUr_3JEEFlab9O8ceXwoQ_S9OIjroVknQ",
  authDomain: "klick-d6cea.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "klick-d6cea",
  storageBucket: "klick-d6cea.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "860270821976",
  appId: "1:860270821976:web:8797713e45f087b07c002d",
  measurementId: "G-98FB6S9KB9"
};

const app = !getApps().length ? initializeApp(firebaseConfig) : getApp();
const db = getFirestore();
const storage = getStorage();

export { app, db, storage };
```

Comment: Have you tried using `uploadBytes()` with a blob? Can you share your component as well just to confirm where the `addImage` function is triggered from?

Comment: @Dharmaraj I have tried using `uploadBytes()` from this [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70560507/trying-to-add-a-image-to-firebase-v9-storage-with-react-native-expo-and-redux but the image doesn't get uploaded either.

Comment: The code seems to be working fine. Are you sure there are no errors in the browser console/

Comment: @Dharmaraj Yeah there are no errors in the console. Maybe it's the way my firebase is set up? You are able to store the image in the firebase storage with the code?

Comment: Yes, it works for me. Can you try adding `console.log(URL)` and check if you get the URL back?

Comment: @Dharmaraj I tried to console log the snapshot and URL but nothing appears in the console. I think it's stuck at `uploadString(imageRef, selectedFile, 'data_url')` , otherwise it would return something. I have tried console.log the docRef and it does appear in the console so it seems to be a problem with the uploadString.

Comment: Can you create a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) with the exact code that you are running and share it?

Comment: @Dharmaraj https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-minsky-wytrk9 I am able to upload the image on the sandbox but not on my web app somehow.

Comment: @MagnusTan did you manage to get around this? I have more less the same setup. When I try uploadString inside next.js API route it just takes forever and nothing happens. No error nor success message

Comment: @adammo No, couldn't figure it out

Comment: @MagnusTan Just letting you know that it's limited by max header size that can be pushed to firebase servers. So uploadString is limited to 8 or 16KB.